# How to stop a VLC player from another application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vlc, system.diagnostics

I have started the VLC player in my application using this code:

```
Process.Start("C://Program Files//Videolan//VLC//VLC.exe", "\"rtsp://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:554/h264\" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\123.ogg,no-overwrite}");
```

Now I need to stop/close this. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process.Kill();` should do the trick.

A somewhat gentler way would be [Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx), but depends on implementation.

Reference: [Process.Kill Method (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can kill by using the following code

```
try
{   
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("processname"))
    {
        proc.Kill();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: utorrent? Where did that come from?

Comment: Edited your answer for formatting. Use `{}` button, which formats the code block.

Comment: If the OP already have a direct reference to the process, iterating through all current processes is wasteful.

Comment: There is no direct reference to the process. So, this option worked!

Comment: There is, @Vinshi - Process.Start creates it. Check Process.ID, for example.

Comment: How will i know th ID of the process?

Comment: I want to start the process in a method StartProcess() and stop it is another method StopProcess()